# Are Microsoft time zone names in TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION structure ever translated?

Tags: windows, winapi, timezone

The answer appears to be no, however I have seen one customer trace that showed the local time zone name in Spanish.  Source of the information is from GetTimeZoneInformation. The document says that these names in the structure will always be English and the user-visible name is coming from a resource file.  It would be great to have confirmation either way.  To be clear, it is this structure:

```
typedef struct _TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION {
  LONG       Bias;
  WCHAR      StandardName[32];
  SYSTEMTIME StandardDate;
  LONG       StandardBias;
  WCHAR      DaylightName[32];
  SYSTEMTIME DaylightDate;
  LONG       DaylightBias;
} TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION, *PTIME_ZONE_INFORMATION;
```

Will StandardName and DaylightName ever be non-English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure where you read they were English only.  From the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725481.aspx):

> Both `StandardName` and `DaylightName` are localized according to the current user default UI language.

Also, on modern Windows, you should mostly be using the `DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` structure, with APIs such as `GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation`, instead of the classic `GetTimeZoneInformation` function.  This structure contains the same standard and daylight names, and are localized as well.

When used as intended, these structures are filled with information from the Windows registry, under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`.   Each entry has four strings that are pertinent:

- The `Std` value is the localized name to be used when standard time is in effect.  This gets mapped to the `StandardName` field in the structures.
- The `Dlt` value is the localized name to be used when daylight time is in effect.  This gets mapped to the `DaylightName` field in the structures.
- The `Display` value is the localized name used to generically represent the time zone entry, and is used when showing a list of time zones - such as in the Windows control panel, or with `tzutil.exe` on the command line, or with `TimeZoneInfo.DisplayName` in .NET.  It is not part of either Win32 structure.
- The **key** of the registry entry is never localized.  It is always in English, and is a unique identifier for the time zone.  In a `DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` structure, it corresponds to the `TimeZoneKeyName` field.  In .NET it corresponds to `TimeZoneInfo.Id`.  Also keep in mind that while the key *usually* matches the English form of the standard name, there are a few exceptions where it does not.  Additionally, a specific key's name is guaranteed to never change, while the localized values under it could, in theory.

Here, you can see how the display names look in the Windows control panel in English and in Chinese.   Similar localization occurs with the standard and daylight names:

[image: Windows Time Zone Control Panels]

And lastly - IMHO these names are quite rubbish in many cases.  For example, there is no such thing as "GMT Daylight Time" - it's actually called "British Summer Time".  The only good source of localized time zone names is in the [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/), which you can either consume directly, or through libraries such as [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) in C and Java, or my [TimeZoneNames](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames) library for .NET.

Comment: Great answer. Missed the line towards the bottom of GetTimeZoneInformation.  Seems odd that Microsoft would decide to translate all the strings, especially since the structure is not something that is going to be visible to the UI.  Thanks for your help.